# FRITZ!Box as a DNS for a Domain Controller?

Tags: networking, dns, active-directory, windows-server-2016, fritzbox

Recently I've activated a Domain Controller at my place, it seems quite crazy but I wanted it to learn how to use Active Directory and how to integrate it in a software that I'm writing.

It's well known that AD for working properly requires a DNS that allows to clients to find the DC and currently I left the defaults setting allowing the DC to work even as a DNS server. It works great but obiviously if I shut down the DC the domain members can't surf Internet so I wanted to delegate the DNS role to my FRITZ!Box Router creating a record that redirects my clients to the server's static IP.

It's possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The clients can have multiple DNS servers in their configuration. In fact its a good idea to have more then one, in case that primary DNS server goes down. So, If the DC is a DNS server, and the clients are domain members then set the clients first DNS to the DC. If your Fritzbox or router or whatever supports DNS then set it up and configure the clients to point to that device as a secondary. You can then add an external DNS server (like google - 8.8.8.8) as a third dns server. With 3 DNS servers that should keep you up and running for the most part. BTW, Domain controller services should be installed on a server, and the server should be left on, 24/7, that's why they call it a server. It serves other functions besides DNS.

Comment: Thank you! I'll follow your advice. I know that DC should operate 24/7 but mine is in an homelab environment and I'm the only user so I think that it's a big waste to run a computer 24/7 just to answer to some authentication requests.